# WordPress/jQuery pagination plugin for multiple lists

Tags: plugin-recommendation, jquery, pagination, ajax, jquery-ui

I have 3 shortcodes. Each of them will be displaying a list.

PS> the lists do NOT contain wordpress posts/pages.

Is there any WordPress plugin that can achieve the purpose?

OR

Please suggest me a jQuery plugin that uses Ajax to fetch subsequent paged data and can work with my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [**jpaging**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jpaging) before which is simple ,easy and highly customizable.